# Querying 4 MySQL tables in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin

I'm building a forums site and I would like to display all the threads to users in the following format:

```
_________________________________________________________________________
Thread Title
Last Post: Username at Date, Started By: Username at Date
_________________________________________________________________________
```

This is what I've come up with:

```
         SELECT TD.id       thread_id,
                TD.sub_cat  thread_cat,
                TD.title    thread_title,
                TD.date     thread_date,
                TD.status   thread_status,
                TD.stick    thread_stick,

                US.username user,

                GR.color group_color

        FROM fr_thread AS TD
        INNER JOIN user AS US ON TD.user_id = US.id
        INNER JOIN user_group AS GR ON US.user_group = GR.id
        ORDER BY TD.stick
```

While I'm displaying all the threads, I would also like the username's be to coloured according to what user group they are in. Therefore, I also have to query for that.

Although, I've come up with most of query, **I'm stuck as how to query for Username, group color, date of the last poster.**

Here is roughly what my DB design looks like:

```
user:
id
user_group

user_group:
id
color

fr_thread:
id
sub_cat
user_id
date

fr_reply:
id
thread_id
user_id
date
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: You need to double aliasing join on user table to get both thread creator and last replier, see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT  

    TD.id as thread_id , 
    TD.sub_cat as thread_sub_cat , 
    TD.user_id as thread_started_user_id , 
    TD.date as thread_started_on , 

    US1.name as thread_author , 
    US2.id as last_reply_user_id , 
    US2.name as last_reply_user_name , 

    USG1.color as thread_author_color ,  
    USG2.color as lat_reply_user_color , 

    RE.date as last_reply_date 

FROM  

    fr_thread TD join user US1 on TD.user_id = US1.id

    join user_group USG1 on USG1.id = US1.user_group 

    join fr_reply RE on RE.thread_id = TD.id

    join user US2 on US2.id = RE.user_id 

    join user_group USG2 on USG2.id = US2.user_group
```

Created 2 aliases  for `user` table as `US1` and `US2` and there are 2 involved ( creator and last replier) similary for `user_group`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/951c0b/1